# WIX installer: How to create environment variable from vswhere.exe output

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, wix3.11

I have a window installer XML (WIX) installer.
I use Visual Studio vswhere.exe to find out Visual Studio InstallationPath and InstanceId for further usage in my WIX code, see below:

```
 <SetProperty Id="InstallationPathProf2019"
                 Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /C &quot;&quot;[VS_INSTALLER_DIR_PATH]\vswhere.exe&quot; -products Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Professional -property InstallationPath -version [\[]16.0,17.0[\)] > [TempFolder]InstallationPathProf2019.txt&quot; &amp;&amp; set /P VS_2019_INSTALLATIONPATH=&lt;[TempFolder]InstallationPathProf2019.txt"
                   Before="InstallationPathProf2019" Sequence="execute" >NOT REMOVE="ALL"</SetProperty>
     <CustomAction Id="InstallationPathProf2019" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"/>
        
     <SetProperty Id="InstanceIdProf2019"
                Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /C &quot;&quot;[VS_INSTALLER_DIR_PATH]vswhere.exe&quot; -products Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Professional -property InstanceId -version [\[]16.0,17.0[\)] > [TempFolder]InstanceIdProf2019.txt  &amp;&amp; set /P VS_2019_INSTANCEID=&lt;[TempFolder]InstanceIdProf2019.txt&quot;"
                Before="InstanceIdProf2019" Sequence="execute" >NOT REMOVE="ALL"</SetProperty>
     <CustomAction Id="InstanceIdProf2019" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"/>
```

in addition, I use set directory with the value retrieved from vswhere as following:

```
<SetDirectory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Value="[%VS_2019_INSTALLATIONPATH]\Test" Sequence="execute"  />
```

Which doesn't work:

> return empty string - MSI (c) (28:F8) [12:15:12:623]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY property. Its value is '\Test'.

When I use predefined environment variable it work:

```
<SetDirectory Id="USERPROFILDIR" Value="[%USERPROFILE]\MyTest" Sequence="first"  />
```

I see in log file:

> PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERPROFILDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Users\donnam\MyTest'.

Why in my case it returns empty string? can't I set a value of environment variable and use it afterwards on my WIX code?

P.S. performing the above in CMD (not through WIX) I see environment variable is created:
[set environment from vswhere output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWiSS.png)

I hope someone can help!

Comment: I see no explicit or implicit mention of, or code from a [[tag:batch-file]]. Can you please edit your question to explain how that is relevant, or remove that tag. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use **setx** to create environment variable instead of **set**.

More information about **setx** can be found at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx